# Is it okay to download data directly to watch OS from server

Tags: ios, swift

So I'm trying to make a watchOS app for a music streaming app, and I found an example pretty much close to what I'm going to make.
(https://github.com/belm/BaiduFM-Swift)

But It seems like the project is kinda outdated. According to the codes below, watch extension is getting required datas like sound, images via HttpRequest. From what I read, watchOS 3 supports Background Connectivity, (which enables app to transfer data more efficiently) and Apple encourages developers to process and get data from the main app.

What is right way to do it? Is there any good example to see?

```
    // play song method in interface controller
    HttpRequest.getSongLink(info.id, callback: {(link:SongLink?) -> Void in
        if let songLink = link {
            DataManager.shareDataManager.curSongLink = songLink
            DataManager.shareDataManager.mp.stop()
            var songUrl = Common.getCanPlaySongUrl(songLink.songLink)
            DataManager.shareDataManager.mp.contentURL = NSURL(string: songUrl)
            DataManager.shareDataManager.mp.prepareToPlay()
            DataManager.shareDataManager.mp.play()
            DataManager.shareDataManager.curPlayStatus = 1

            Async.main{
                self.songTimeLabel.setText(Common.getMinuteDisplay(songLink.time))
            }

            HttpRequest.getLrc(songLink.lrcLink, callback: { lrc -> Void in
                if let songLrc = lrc {
                    DataManager.shareDataManager.curLrcInfo = Common.praseSongLrc(songLrc)
                    //println(songLrc)
                }
            })
        }
    })
```